# WPF ModernUI same footer for all pages

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I'm trying to implement something-like-footer (same content/page for whole app) in my ModernUI WPF app. In mainwindow.xaml I have basic Menu (expanded examples)

```
    <mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
        <mui:LinkGroup DisplayName="Sports">
            <mui:LinkGroup.Links>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Home" Source="/Pages/Home.xaml"/>
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Football" Source="/Pages/Sports/Football.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Handball" Source="/Pages/Sports/Handball.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Basketball" Source="/Pages/Sports/Basketball.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Tennis" Source="/Pages/Sports/Tennis.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Volleyball" Source="/Pages/Sports/Volleyball.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="Beach handball" Source="/Pages/Sports/BeachHandball.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="General settings" Source="/Pages/Settings.xaml" />
                <mui:Link DisplayName="About" Source="/Pages/About.xaml" />
            </mui:LinkGroup.Links>
        </mui:LinkGroup>
    </mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>
```

I have tried adding `<mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>` to grid element, however I get The member "MenuLinkGroups" is not recognized or is not accessible error.

Edit:

I have also tried using `<mui:ModernFrame>` element and adding source with my constant content, after `</mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>` however it doesn't work (it isn't rendered at all).

Any ideas or advices how to get something like footer in ModernUI are highly appreciated.

Many thanks!

Comment: What element is your `<mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups>` nested in? A `Grid`? Does it have `Grid.RowDefinitions` set up?

Comment: No, <mui:ModernWindow.MenuLinkGroups> cannot be in a Grid, as i have written, since it comes up with an error, and per authors note, grid element cannot be used at all in mui:ModernWindow. 

Currently I am working on modifying ModernUI source by my needs (to achieve footer functionality), as that is only possible solution that I have found.

Comment: Ivan: How did it turn out?

Comment: @lahjaton_j I just went through comment history in inbox and saw your comment. I apologize, I'm not sure how I have missed it. 

Sadly, I think that I don't have source code anymore as my friend (who I was working for) gave up from working on this project. 

As far as I can recall, I've forked ModernUI to modify source and added my Footer element. 

If you still need some hints, I can try to dig up source if it is lying somewhere.

Comment: It's OK, switched to mahapps. To be honest, both of the libraries are somewhat lacking in features and especially in documentation.

Comment: @lahjaton_j I agree about the documentation. As far as I can remember, at the time in 2014, I was also in dilemma between choosing Mahapps.Metro or ModernUI :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the ModernWindow style and template. There is a good tutorial here:

http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3789b7/modern-ui-for-wpf-application-by-example-default-window-wit/