# ModernUI Footer like control on all pages

Tags: c#, wpf, modern-ui

I have been working with ModernUI, does the library have a a footer control thats ever present for all pages.

I tried this [WPF ModernUI same footer for all pages](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23596190/wpf-modernui-same-footer-for-all-pages) had no success( am new to wpf)

Comment: please provide code for what you've already tried

Answer (score 0):

You can define your page style with header and footer in app.xaml:

```
<Style x:Key="HeaderFooterPageStyle" TargetType="Page">
    <Setter Property="Template">
        <Setter.Value>
            <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type Page}">
                <Grid Background="{TemplateBinding Background}">
                    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
                        <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
                    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

                    <!-- Header -->
                    <Border Grid.Row="0" Background="Red">
                        <TextBlock Text="Header"/>
                    </Border>

                    <!-- Body -->
                    <ContentPresenter Grid.Row="1"/>

                    <!-- Footer -->
                    <Border Grid.Row="2" Background="Red">
                        <TextBlock Text="Footer"/>
                    </Border>
                </Grid>
            </ControlTemplate>
        </Setter.Value>
    </Setter>
</Style>
```

Then set style to all pages:

```
Style="{StaticResource HeaderFooterPageStyle}"
```

Comment: this footer should be on main window and not on every page

Comment: Ok, Austine. Set style only on main window. Style="{StaticResource HeaderFooterPageStyle}"

Comment: You said "page" and now "window". If it is window, you need to change the TargetType = "Window"

Comment: Try to help me from this link http://www.c-sharpcorner.com/UploadFile/3789b7/modern-ui-for-wpf-application-by-example-default-window-wit/  am using a style ModernWindow.xaml to apply to my main window.